# Compairing the force required to traverse a curb between a wide and a narrow wheelchair tire

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

My hypothesis is that a large volume tire (a balloon tire) will roll over an obstacle with less force applied to the wheel than a narrow tire inflated to the same firmness (casing tension or hoop stress as predicted by LaPlace’s Law).

My problem is accounting for the fact that the balloon tire results in an overall larger wheel diameter giving it a slight mechanical advantage. In a simple experiment with a fish scale, the wheel with the balloon tire rolled over a 20mm thick board with almost two Kg less pulling force than the narrow tire even after the difference in wheel diameter was taken into account (10 trials each, p<.005). The diameter of the wheel with the balloon tire is 660mm and 633mm for the narrow tire. According to the formula for the force of a wheel over a curb:

$$F=\frac{Mg\sqrt{2Rh-h^2 }}{R-h}$$

where =force, =wheel radius, ℎ=height of obstruction (curb), =mass, the balloon tire would have a 2% advantage based on the diameter. I decreased each of the values in the 10 trials for the narrow tire by 2%. By using this correction factor I am stating that the observed force differences are due to the tire volume alone.  Is it logical?

Comment: An interesting hypothesis worth investigating, but to test it systematically requires measurements for more than one curb height. (You may already have done this, but it isn't obvious from the question.) For example, is the 2 kg force difference associated with the physics of rolling over the curb or simply due to differences in the rolling friction of the two tires?  Before trusting your model, at the very least I recommend making measurements for h=0cm and h=4cm.  More information, e.g actual tire widths and inflation pressures, might also help people understand the physical system.